# Error with adding "rect" element to document by c# program

Tags: c#, svg, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to add some "rect" elements to svg document through c# console app.
An "rect" elements are adding and they are present in structure of svg document, but they are invisible.

When i added "rect" element manually then everything was okay.

Svg image after app execution
[image: app result]

Svg after adding "rect" manually
[image: manual result]

There is my code

```
    public static MemoryStream Draw(Stream stream)

    {
        var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

        var svgDocument = XDocument.Load(stream);

        if (svgDocument.Root != null)
        {
            var gElements = svgDocument.Root.Elements("{http://www.w3.org/2000/svg}g");

            var damageLayer = gElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Attribute("id")?.Value == "Damages");

            var damage = new XElement("rect", new XAttribute("x", 205), new XAttribute("y", 205), new XAttribute("width", 15), new XAttribute("height", 15));

            damageLayer.Add(damage);
        }

        svgDocument.Save(outputStream);

        return outputStream;
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions or ways to solve that problem? If you do, please, let me know. Any help appreciates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How to remove xmlns from XElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40517306/c-sharp-how-to-remove-xmlns-from-xelement)

Comment: Are you sure that this problem is caused by "xmlns" attribute?

Comment: You change the default namespace to nothing
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp `Default Namespace`
The alternative would be to provide the proper svg namespace in your rect

Comment: I removed "xmlns" attribute, but nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the rect in the SVG namespace i.e.

```
XNamespace namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var damage = new XElement(namespace + "rect", ...
```